# Run older kernel on Ubuntu with secure boot

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, secure-boot

On Ubuntu 20.04, I am trying to run some piece of proprietary software junk that works only with kernel 5.8 instead of the current kernel 5.15.

So, I installed the kernel 5.8 using a mainline script which worked fine. However, now secure boot (more precisely shim) is refusing to boot with this older kernel. So, it seems that I need to sign it. Is there some easy way to do this?

(Disabling secure boot is not an option as then proprietary drivers refuse to run.)

Comment: I am not entirely sure if Ubuntu use shim (or if you can opt to use it even if it isn't used by default). IIRC with shim it is possible to keep SB enabled but practically disabling the checking on the kernel by running `mokutil --disable-validation` or so.

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu uses shim. In fact, the whole problem is that on booting the kernel 5.8 it says 'error: bad shim signature'. However, after doing mokutil --disable-validation this problem still occurs.

Comment: More precisely, after doing mokutil --disable-validation, in the blue screen on boot i can 'change secure boot stage', i.e., disable secure boot. But this doesn't help because it has the same effect as disabling secure boot in the bios, namely, third party drivers refuse to work.

Comment: @phlegmax I'm not sure what you mean by `in the blue screen on boot i can 'change secure boot stage'`. (But really my experience with shim and SB is scarce.) The point / purpose of `mokutil --disable-validation`, AFAIK, is merely to tell grub not to request shim to validate kernel images (and IIRC, to tell shim not to validate grub as well). There seems to be alternate way, which you may want to try: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/UEFI-secure-boot-and-shim.html

Comment: @John: Calm down. I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: I found an apparent solution to my problem, but didn't try it yet: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/mainline-kernel-signieren-uefi/